# Knowing if a value can be called

Tags: lua

*Note that this question is about pure Lua. I do not have access to any module or the C side. Additionally, I can not use the IO, the OS or the debug library.*

What I'm trying to make is a function that receives, as parameters:

- a number that is an ammount of second
- a callable value

By 'a callable value', I mean a value that can be called. This can be:

- a function
- a table with a metatable that allows calling (through a `__call` metamethod)

Here's an example of a callable table:

```
local t = {}
setmetatable(t, {
  __call = function() print("Hi.") end
})
print(type(t)) --> table
t() --> Hi.
```

Here's the function:

```
function delay(seconds, func)
  -- The second parameter is called 'func', but it can be anything that is callable.
  coroutine.wrap(function()
    wait(seconds) -- This function is defined elsewhere. It waits the ammount of time, in seconds, that it is told to.
    func() -- Calls the function/table.
  end)()
end
```

But I have a problem. I want the function to throw an error if the parameter 'func' is not callable.

I can check if it is a function. But what if it is a table with a metatable that allows calling?
If the metatable of the table is not protected by a `__metatable` field, then, I can check the metatable to know if it is callable, but, otherwise, how would I do it?

Note that I have also thought about trying to call the 'func' parameter with `pcall`, to check if it is callable, but to do that, I need to call it prematurely.

Basically, here's the problem: **I need to know if a function/table is callable, but without trying to call it.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, if the metatable does not want you to be able to get it (by defining `__metatable` to being something special), then you're not going to get it. Not from Lua.

However, if you want to cheat, you can always use `debug.getmetatable`, which will return the metatable associated with that object.

---

You don't have to prematurely call anything with `pcall`. Observe:

```
pcall(function(...) return PossibleFunction(...) end, <insert arguments here>)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I do not have access to the debug library either, I edited my original post to specify it.

Comment: Well, so that means there is no way to know is a value is callable without trying to call it, except using the debug library? If so, that's kind of annoying, since I'm a perfectionnist and I want to be able to call all callable value, while still being able to throw an error if the value is not callable.

Comment: Well, I need to know if the value is callable. If it is, I wait a certain ammount of seconds and then call it. Otherwise, I throw an error. If I try calling the value, it will run and will do things that weren't supposed to be done yet.

Comment: @Mark: Well, no, there's nothing you can do. You can test for obvious failures (not a function or user-data), but ultimately you're going to have to hope for the best. Just use the `pcall` at the final site of the call and fail then.

Comment: I thought about using `pcall` at the final site of the call, but I dislike the idea of the error taking too many time to show up. But, I think this is what I'm going to do: I'll first check if it is a function or a table. If it isn't, it errors. Otherwise, it waits the ammount of seconds specified and then tries to call the function. If it can't be called, throws an error. Otherwise, does nothing.

Comment: Well, I guess there's no way to get exactly what I want, I'll stick with what I can do. Thank you for helping.

Comment: I like this tell-don't-ask way. I used to do a "isCallable" function, but I might copy this style. Is the anonymous function mandatory? Can't you just do `pcall(PossibleFunction, params)` ?

Comment: Note that userdata is callable also, in the same way a table is. The general pattern in Lua is to just attempt to call the value. If it is callable, it works. If not, the attempt to call will itself throw an error. The only reason for interposing a `pcall` here is to change the error thrown.

Comment: @RBerteig: The reason for the `pcall` is so that the current Lua thread of execution will not stop (unless you want it to). You don't necessarily want certain things to error out to the user. Sometimes, you really do want Lua to just stop. But sometimes you don't. Sometimes, you want to be able to bypass the error.

Comment: @Nicol The OP did say that the plan was to "throw an error if the parameter 'func' is not callable", which I interpreted to mean call `error()`. That assumes that the caller has either used `pcall` already, or is otherwise prepared to handle that case gracefully. If one wishes to prevent an error from ever leaking out of the OP's `delay` function, then it should use a `pcall` to catch it and handle the aftermath appropriately. But that is an implementation detail compared to the larger question of testing for callability. There, the answer is just call (or `pcall`) it.

Answer (score 2):

```lua
function iscallable(x)
    if type(x) == 'function' then
        return true
    elseif type(x) == 'table' then
        -- It would be elegant and quick to say
        -- `return iscallable(debug.getmetatable(x))`
        -- but that is actually not quite correct
        -- (at least in my experiments), since it appears
        -- that the `__call` metamethod must be a *function* value
        -- (and not some table that has been made callable)
        local mt = debug.getmetatable(x)
        return type(mt) == "table" and type(mt.__call) == "function"
    else
        return false
    end
end

return iscallable
```

Then you can do

```
> = iscallable(function() end)
true
> = iscallable({})
false
> = iscallable()
false
> = iscallable(nil)
false
> x = {}
> setmetatable(x, {__call=function() end})
> = iscallable(x)
true
```

If you don't have access to the debug library, then you may have trouble being totally accurate since you can mess with metatables. You could use `pcall` but its hard to separate out the errors properly. Even if you search for a particular error string as in the other answer here, that might be because of something inside the function being called not being callable, not this particular value not being callable, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This attempt at refining Nicol's answer still has the problem that it needs to call the table, but it tells whether a supplied table actually was callable or not. Even if the table was callable, `pcall()` will return `false` if there is an error caused during the execution of the `__call()` metamethod.

```
local result = {pcall(PossibleFunction, ...)}

if not result[1] then
    if result[2]:match"^attempt to call" then
        error("The provided value is not callable.")
    else
        -- Table was callable but failed. Just hand on the error.
        error(result[2])
    end
end

-- Do something with the results:
for i = 2, #result do
    print(result[i])
end
```

Checking the error message in this way however does not feel very "clean" (what if the used Lua interpreter was e.g. modified with localized error messages?).